# Will this MOSFET H-bridge motor control with end of travel disable switches work?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, mosfet, motor-controller, home-automation

Thank you for taking an interest.
Very very amateur here, but after a 2+ week of reading howtos and SE posts, validation would be greatly appreciated.

**Context:**

- Control by ESP32 MCU
- 30 V motor is a very short duration (1-2 seconds) garage lock
- Lock has End Of Travel (EOT) contacts referred to as EOT-lock and EOT-unlock in the schematic
- ESP32 pins P-lock and P-unlock will apply 3.3 V to operate the lock before turning on the screw
- MCU will read the EOT-x switches to turn off the control pins and engage the main drive
- LED 1 & 2 will indicate control signal (this specific transistor w. LED without R worked for me before - just enough Vbe drop across transistor)
- **EOT-x should disable the control to protect from motor burn out even if MCU is stuck**
- EOT LEDs 3 & 4 should indicate the lock position
- This is a one off for personal use, not a product. I could order a PCB or make my own, both options require a bit of expense $ or labor, would be great to know if this "might work" or "no way".

**Questions**

- Any mistakes in general?
- Can I omit flyback diodes? Found conflicting information here on SO.
- My understanding of P-channel vs N-channel MOSFETs is still weak, is the schematic correct?
- From datasheets the FETs seem reasonable for 1-3 A for 1-2 seconds, not sure if I read them correctly.
- Is using a voltage divider for driving MOSFETs with 15 V sane? Would a Zener be better and why?

Thank you.

Edit: Added the diodes and PCB. Please let me know if there is something I need to fix on the PCB. NOTE: PCB will get faint inkjet heat transfer which I will fix with a sharpie. This "worked" before, but does limit the sophistication to 1mm+ lines and spacing that my "drawing skills" can maintain. (this is a one-off for personal use + learning).

Edit2: adding diodes to prevent shoot through

Edit3: adding more transistors and current limiting R per @MikroPower
with 1 less transistor, should work, right? Also using +12 V instead of voltage divider.
latest schematic at the top:

Edit3: removing old images.

Edit4: removing 12 V adding Zener diodes, fixing EOT short.
[image]
[image]

Comment: with R5,6,7,8 added, do I still need R1 and R2 ?

Comment: I guess I do need them or a signal from either side would have the same effect on both left and right.

Comment: I’d suggest you add current limiting. There are plenty of integrated solutions for this task with various protections built in.

Comment: Your latest implementation will not work. The gate drivers toggle between GND and +12V, but the MOSFETs are on a 24V supply. Also, your limit switch inputs cause a short to GND for the lock and unlock inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections @PStechPaul.  P-ch is a bit confusing.

Comment: Those won't work either. Q2 will always be ON. You need to swing the gate drives fully between GND and +24V. Why not just use the circuit I have provided? Or draw up your own idea and simulate it using CircuitLab?

Comment: I use a BTS7960, H bridge from china, cost is less than $5 US, Shipping varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it might be useful to draw up one or more alternative circuits for an NMOS/PMOS bridge driver:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRF5Hh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Currents]

This was tested using two PWM signals with 10 us rise and fall times, to see if there is any cross-conduction for a PWM signal. I have not added the LEDs or the end-of-travel interlocks, but they can be the same as my previous circuit. I think this is the simplest implementation of an NMOS/PMOS gate driver, but I welcome any suggestion for improvement.

Here are plots for separate application of signals to each side of the bridge, showing no sign of cross-conduction or instability with 1 ms rise and fall times.

[image: Voltages]

[image: Currents]

Comment: THANK YOU. This is so much simpler than the monster I've arrived at with all the feedback. Don't get me wrong, I'm glad to learn, but building that was impractical. If I had to order large quantity of those I'd chose smd but for 1 off - 2 relays beat 26 parts on home-etched pcb hands down :D

Answer (score 2):

1. You must make sure that the upper and the lower MOSFET are not on at the same time, this would cause a unlimited current.
2. If you do not know the maximum current over the coil, then do not build it on the edge. So use MOSFETs with more current.
3. You should add additional free running diodes, do not think that the internal diodes will do all the work.
4. You have to limit the gate-voltage! 20V is the maximum at the NTF2955, but you should use 10V or may be 12V as the limit.

Comment: thanks for the reply
 1) does the schema not ensure the "not at the same time" ? that was the main question about the diagram.
2)I know the motor consumes under 3A, maybe even under 1A, I'll doublecheck.
3) added diodes. thank you
4) gate  voltage - does v. divider not do the trick ? 12v is present elsewhere and I can bring it, divider seemed more neat.

Comment: Disagree on point 3. Body diodes should be fine for this application.

Comment: @Tjunkie - The problem is the short time between the transition. This job is very slowly, so you can make it in a way that the gate-capacitor of the lower MOSFET can be discharged very fast (to go off) and loaded slowly. The upper MOSFET have to be charged fast (to go off) and discharged slowly. Slowly means milliseconds. This you can do with a parallel diode + resistor in each gate-path. Add some 12V Z-diodes between source and gate and limit the current, so that the Z-diodes do not burn down.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - Okay, right here it is okay to use them. The big voltage drop is not a problem.

Comment: Added diodes, another hour of education... Did I get this correctly ?  Turning OFF the gate through diode (fast) turning ON through R (slow). This is getting waaaay to involved compared to re-using a SPDT relay in the old broken garage lock controller :D But I'm learning a lot. TBH, too many components for a simple motor reversing circuit :D.

Comment: Gate cap. listed as 492pF, w. 15v and 10k 2Rc looks to be 9ms, is this a good R value? Or should I use 1K
Disclaimer: just used online calculator with numbers from the datasheet.

Comment: Both answers helped a great deal, don't know how to do this "accept" thing properly

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to implement a full bridge with NMOS and PMOS:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv8mQ8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Currents]

The logic states are shown on the schematic with H and L for 3.3V and 0V. The states change every 100 ms, and simulate raising and lowering (up and down), and the action of the limit switches.

Comment: thank you for the schematic, values take much time to find. To confirm understanding: Q3 and Q4 are just to connect the gates to 30v or 0. R7 is the current limiting. D4 & D5 limit the gates to 10V. questions: is zener better than V divider? and to simplify this I can use 12v supply that is also available. Why doesn't pull up R1 (in my diagram) work, why use the Q3 an Q4 ?

Comment: I think this is looking good. This is a half bridge, so you create two of them in the layout. @Tjunkie - You can simulate this now in LTspice and then etch the PCB and build it up. T7 is used that the gate does not swing, this is happening if you have several gates on one driver. If you would use a voltage divider, then the rising/falling of the voltage can be so slowly that the MOSFET get hot.

Comment: Both answers helped a great deal, don't know how to do this "accept" thing properly. VV LTspice - I tried to figure this out, maybe didn't find the right software... gave up some time ago. "Everycircuit" is at my "level" of knowledge. But of course it doesn't simulate actual components.

Comment: LTspice is a application what everyone who like to develop electronic circuits should know ans use. It makes things more easy and help to understand this behaviour of the components much better. https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm getting about 100 amps through the half-bridge when I drive the "up" input high. These inputs need a current limiting resistor when being driven by a 3.3V logic signal. I'm taking a fresh look now.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the model for the 2955 or 3055. Things are now working as expected. I had to save and insert because I got a notice that my free trial had expired. I'll see if I can finish the full bridge

Comment: Thanks a ton. Could you take a look at my 3rd iteration. I tried to simplify yours a little. where instead of your Q2 controlling Q3 and Q4, I am using MCU 3.3v to control Q8 and Q12. I hope it will do the same thing.

Comment: No small feat to pickup LTSpice - UI is murder. EasyEda is soo much easier to use. And looking for the component models ... :sigh:

Comment: Separate N and P drivers (or might as well use bootstrap at this point), with dead time implemented, is strongly recommended above, really even just 3.3V it's kind of marginal using a "power CMOS inverter" scheme, let alone 30V. At high voltages, there is considerable time spent where both transistors are fully on, shorting out the supply for a significant fraction of a microsecond.

Comment: @Tjunkie The LTspice UI is pretty bad, yes. But SPICE is the industry standard for simulations, and almost every manufacturer provides SPICE models (Note that any unencrypted models labelled as Pspice models will work with LTspice as well, perhaps with minor syntax modifications.) Unfortunately, no one has yet made (to my knowledge) a better interface for a SPICE simulator that's available for free.

Comment: easyeda.com is free and building a schematic in that ui is a lot more intuitive (at least for me). Turns out it has a built-in LTspice thing, just need to learn to use that. still a learning curve but mostly in spice not in basic placing/moving components